# Past tense. "when Tom went [was going, would go, used to go] to high school."?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, past-tense

I'm confused with how to mention past habits.

If Tom is a student now, you say "Tom goes to high school", right?

If Tom already graduated, are these three all OK?

- A-1) Tom went to high school until last year.
- A-2) Tom would go to high school until last year.
- A-3) Tom used to go to high school until last year.

I doubt "Tom was going to high school until last year." is a correct sentence.  Is my understanding correct?

How about the sentences below?

B) Tom was dating Becky when he

- B-1) went to high school.
- B-2) would go to high school.
- B-3) used to go to high school.
- B-4) was going to high school.

Which sentence would be most appropriate? Tenses are the most difficult part of English to me.

Comment: would go in your second sentence is not past tense. Exception: Tom would go to school when his father was in town, but not when he was out of town.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one `A`, the first and third ones are correct

> Tom would go to high school until last year.

^ is technically correct but the sentence does not flow well in a way

It is more grammatically correct in one writes

> Tom would go to school last year.

> I doubt "Tom was going to high school until last year." is a correct sentence. Is my understanding correct?

^ This sentence might be correct, I think its grammatically correct, but it sounds weird, so its better to stick with the other ones you have mentioned.

For `B`, all 4 correct, as they all imply how Tom dated Becky using **past tense**.

---

For the comment on the following:

> But I still do not understand why "would go to school until last year" is weird while "would go to school last year" is OK. Would you explain what makes this difference, please?

To be honest, both these sentences actually have different meanings, "would go to school until last year", implies that Tom stopped going to school at the start of last year, and "would go to school last year", means Tom used to go to school last year and ended school probably at the end of the year.

E.g. The current year is 2022, put the first sentence into perspective (would go to school until last year), then it means Tom stopped going to school at the start of 2021. To clarify, "until" means "up to", so Tom stopped going to school when 2021 started. The second sentence (would go to school last year), implies that Tom stopped going to school when 2022 started.

Comment: Why is A-2 incorrect?  I learnt you use "would" to talk about your past habit.

Comment: its technically correct but it sounds weird, better to choose 1 or 3

Comment: Would you tell me what makes the difference?  When do you use "would" for a past habit and it doesn't sound weird?

Comment: Usually its "tom would go to school last year" instead of "tom would go to school until last year"

Comment: Is my answer alright now @kuwabara? thx

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I do appreciate it.  But I still do not understand why "would go to school until last year" is weird while "would go to school last year" is OK.  Would you explain what makes this difference, please?

Comment: Ah ok ill edit my post to answer your question @kuwabara

Comment: Going to school isn't thought of as a 'habit' in the usual sense, since attending school and  then going out to work are a normal part of life for most people. _Tom would go to school_ isn't idiomatic, but we can say _Tom would usually take the bus to school_. _Tom was going to high school until last year_ is fine - we can also say _Tom was at [BrE] / in [AmE] school_.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

*Go* in *go to school* is not the same as the normal word *go*: it is **already** habitual.

Therefore your A2 and B2 are not idiomatic in this sense. You **can** say *He would go to school ...* but this would refer to his daily journey to school, not to the fact or period when he was attending school.

Your A1 is normal. A3 is possible, but implies that something unexpected had happened to make him stop.

In your B, again, B1 is more natural, B3 is possible (with the same implication as A3), and so is B4; but to me the most natural choice is *when he was at high school*.

Comment: Colin, I know it's a pain but it would be easier to follow your argument if you reposted the sentences....

Comment: @Lambie: fair comment. I'll try and remember to in future